# Writing cross-compatible python2/python3 code in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I've taken care to make sure library works on both python2 and python3, but pycharm adds some vexatious red squiggles as seen below

[image]

If I switch the project interpreter to python 3.5 instead, the nag just moves onto the other import.  **Which inspection is this?  I want to turn it off.**

Comment: Alt-Enter will tell you which inspection(s), then hit right to see options including *"disable inspection"*. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe This particular inspection doesn't give the option to disable it in the context menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like it's a known bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17934 The last activity is in 2015 on one of the linked issues basically saying "Yup, that happens". I would suspect it's either [tag:wont-fix] or [tag:by-design].

Comment: Have you considered using the `future` package to solve this instead? This will resolve your issue by pushing the code out of your package...

Comment: I hadn't considered it, that's a good suggestion.  You should add an answer ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although it doesn't solve the issue for all cases, you can solve this particular problem by using the `future` package.

As you can see [here](http://python-future.org/imports.html#imports-of-builtins), the `future` package provides its own version of `builtins` for python 2 and python 3.  By relying on this package instead of doing it yourself, you can import `future`'s implementation of builtins, thus removing the problematic code and avoiding Pycharm's (erroneous) error.